# SciPy's Newton function does not find the intersection point

Tags: python, scipy, newtons-method, scipy-optimize

I am trying to understand why the code below does not return -1.17 but instead returns -6.67e-09. What does this number actually tell me?

If I alter the estimation from 0 to -1 it *does* correctly compute -1.17. However, if I would have to do this for 100+ different functions, I would have to write a while-loop for each making the calculation process incredibly slow.

Is this simply the way this is calculated or am I missing a specific parameter for this case?

```
from scipy.optimize import newton


def f(x):
    return x**2-3


def g(x):
    return x**3

def insection():
    def difference(x):
        return g(x) - f(x)
    insection_point_value = newton(difference, 0)

    return insection_point_value 

print(insection())
```

```
Returns: -6.665555511432543e-09
Has to be: -1.1745594102929802
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Newton-Raphson method**(NR) is highly sensitive to the initial value you provide.

Check the graph of the difference function:
[image: graph]
The derivative of the function at `x = 0` is `0`. **NR** being an iterative method, cannot progress from the initial point `x0 = 0` using a zero derivative. That's why, it continues to stay there, instead of converging towards the intended point. Try `x0 = -0.1` and it works, or anything less than that.
Any `x > 0` will continue to fail, because there is another zero derivative at `x = 0.667`, and the iterative method will *slide into the valley*, to use layman language.

The weird decimal value that you get (instead of `0`)is an artifact of floating-point math, discretized values for the function, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

The Newton-Raphson method is a way to find a good approximation for the root of a real-valued function (In your case: `f(x) =x**3 - x**2 + 3`). It's an iterative algorithm that relies heavily on the starting point (`x0` I mean).

So, I suggest using more than one starting point and then get the most common root. This code explains what I mean:

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import newton
>>> from collections import Counter


>>> # using [-10, -9, -8, ..., 8, 9, 10] as starting point(s)
>>> roots = newton(lambda x: x**3 - x**2 +3, range(-11, 11))

>>> # find the most common root
>>> root, count = Counter(roots).most_common(1)[0]
>>> root
-1.17455941029298
>>> count
17
```

Which means that out of the 22 starting points, 17 of them converged to -1.17

Answer (score 0):

You can provide function derivative: `fprime` - see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html). This should make the search much more stable.

Comment: Interesting, that works for most values, but if a zero-derivative point is entered as `x0`, the method still fails with the warning:  
`RuntimeWarning: derivative was zero.`

Comment: One can first check derivative, and if it's zero, then add some random value.